# How can I use sum?

Tags: python, odoo-10, odoo

On my tree view I should show the total (last line) of a specific field. with a float field it works with no problem but as the field is a string it doesn't . so how can I let it work?

old_var is a float field 
my_variable is a Char field
my_variable should be HH:M:S on the view

```py
my_variable=str(datetime.timedelta(hours=old_var))
```

```xml
<field name="my_variable"  sum="total"/>
```

Comment: So you cant to show the total for example :   14:34:13  so you want to sum Hours and minutes and seconds?!! you cannot do that in odoo only if you change the behavior of the tree view. `Javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your `old_var` and use Odoo's `float_time` widget.

```xml
<field name="old_var" widget="float_time" sum="total"/>
```

If you really need to show seconds, you have to create your own widget. But you can use Odoo's `float_time` widget for that, too, by extending it.

Comment: I have no idea about how to create it

Comment: I looked into it, and it's not that easy i have thought. The widget itself is very small (in lines of code measurement). There is a js function `format_value()` in `addons/web/static/src/js/framework/formats.js` which has to be overridden or extended to get another format case with seconds.